How to Explode JSON Strings into Multiple Columns using PySpark
I have a dataframe with one column of string datatype. Each string line represents an API request that returns a json.
After create the DataFrame and parsing the data, I'm getting the following result:
def fn_process_data(data):

    spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]')\
                                .appName('sparkdf')\
                                .config("spark.log.level", "OFF")\
                                .getOrCreate()

    ### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    df = spark.createDataFrame([[json.dumps(d)] for d in data])

Result:
+--------------------+                                                          
|                  _1|
+--------------------+
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
|{"abilities": [{"...|
+--------------------+

After got the result I'm trying to explode the rows in new columns, but I'm getting an empty DataFrame.
    schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

    df = df.withColumn("_1", F.explode(F.from_json("_1", schema)))\
           .select("_1.abilities",
                   "_1.base_experience",
                   "_1.cries",
                   "_1.forms",
                   "_1.games_indices",
                   "_1.height",
                   "_1.held_items",
                   "_1.id",
                   "_1.is_default",
                   "_1.location_area_encounters",
                   "_1.moves",
                   "_1.name",
                   "_1.order",
                   "_1.past_abilities",
                   "_1.past_types",
                   "_1.species",
                   "_1.sprites",
                   "_1.stats",
                   "_1.types",
                   "_1.weight")

    df.show()

Result:
+---------+---------------+-----+-----+-------------+------+----------+---+----------+------------------------+-----+----+-----+--------------+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+------+
|abilities|base_experience|cries|forms|games_indices|height|held_items| id|is_default|location_area_encounters|moves|name|order|past_abilities|past_types|species|sprites|stats|types|weight|
+---------+---------------+-----+-----+-------------+------+----------+---+----------+------------------------+-----+----+-----+--------------+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+------+
+---------+---------------+-----+-----+-------------+------+----------+---+----------+------------------------+-----+----+-----+--------------+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+------+

The result I'm expecting is to split the data into columns, like this:
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------------- [...]
|abilities                                                                             |base_experience|cries                           
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------------- [...]
|[{"ability":{"name": "limber", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/7/"}, [...]] |101            |{"latest": "https://raw.[...]
|[{"ability":{"name": "pikachu", "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/3"}, [...]] |103            |{"latest": "https://raw.[...]


How can I achieve this result using functions like "MapType", "explode", etc?

The explode function does not do what you're wanting based on the expected result. Explode is for turning 1 row into N rows by "exploding" something like an array column into 1 row per element of the array. For example, it'd be useful if you wanted to pivot the abilities column to have 1 row per ability for a given pokemon.

With from_json() your schema should be an array of structs in this case, as the data is more complex than an array of string-string maps. The data is truncated in the original provided examples, but the schema would look something like so:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = """
abilities ARRAY<
  STRUCT<name STRING, url STRING>
>,
base_experience INT,
cries STRUCT<latest STRING, legacy STRING>,
forms ARRAY<STRUCT<
  id INT,
  form_name STRING
>>,
games_indices ARRAY<STRUCT<
  game_index INT,
  generation STRUCT<name STRING, url STRING>
>>,
id INT,
name STRING
"""

df = df.select(
  F.from_json(F.col("_1"), schema)
)


Note: this example uses a DDL string syntax to define the schema for simplicity. The same effect can still be achieved with typed PySpark or Scala Spark code.

If this is too verbose or you'd like to let the schema evolve more loosely, you can look at the schema_of_json() built-in function as well.

Is there a way to parse/build the schema automatically using some specific function?

I found a tool to help infer the schema automatically.
I will try to finish the code using it.
link
